# creating weekly scheduled event in mysql

Tags: mysql, scheduled-tasks, mysql-event

error #1064 in the event what wrong i m doing please suggest me some good tutorials, current following mysql docs

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DO BEGIN INSERT INTO week_stats (profileid,likes,dislikes,ragepoints) SELECT id' at line 3


DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT week_stats
ON SCHEDULE EVERY  WEEK 
DO
BEGIN
INSERT INTO week_stats (id,likes,dislikes,points) 
SELECT id,likes,dislikes,points FROM profile;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

mysql version is 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.11.10.1

Comment: Please post the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. You have to specify interval in the EVERY clause, e.g. - 'EVERY 1 WEEK' or 'EVERY 2 WEEK'.

[CREATE EVENT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html).